# use range with numeric value nest 1.7

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, range, nest

I need to add a rangerfilter in nest 1.7 with numeric value,

but the class define GreaterThan with a string

```
namespace Nest
{
    public class RangeFilter : PlainFilter, IRangeFilter, IFieldNameFilter, IFilter
    {
        public RangeFilter();

        public RangeExecution? Execution { get; set; }
        public PropertyPathMarker Field { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string GreaterThan { get; set; }
        public string GreaterThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }
        public string LowerThan { get; set; }
        public string LowerThanOrEqualTo { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }

        protected internal override void WrapInContainer(IFilterContainer container);
    }
}
```

so my query is

```
  {
                    "range": {
                      "NbAnnonce": {
                        "gt": "0"
                      }
```

and not

```
   {
                "range": {
                  "NbAnnonce": {
                    "gt": 0.0
                  }
```

how can i resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
new NumericRangeQuery
{
  Name = "named_query",
  Boost = 1.1,
  Field = "description",
  GreaterThan = 1.0,
  GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 1.1,
  LessThan = 2.1,
  LessThanOrEqualTo = 2.0
}
```

**Json Output**

```
{
  "range": {
    "description": {
      "_name": "named_query",
      "boost": 1.1,
      "gt": 1.0,
      "gte": 1.1,
      "lt": 2.1,
      "lte": 2.0
    }
  }
}
```